# Radius of Convergence of product of power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Is the following statement true?

If $P(z)$ is a power series over $\mathbb C$, then $ P(z) $and $P(z)^n$ have same radius of convergence for any positive integer n.

Comment: Hmm I don't know. I am curious myself. For a holomorphic function, the radius of a convergence of the power series expanded at a point $z_0$ is the distance from $z_0$ to the nearest singularity. Perhaps this can be useful? Also, there is the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem for the radius of convergence: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem

Comment: @dalbrit It shows that the radius of convergence of $P(z)^n$ is always at least as large as that of $P(z)$. The radii need not be identical, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not true. Consider the power series

$$P(z) = \sqrt{1+z} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}z^k.$$

The radius of convergence of $P(z)$ is $1$, since $\sqrt{1+z}$ has a branch point in $-1$. But $P(z)^2 = 1+z$ has infinite radius of convergence.

However, the radius of convergence of $P(z)^n$ is always at least as large as the radius of convergence of $P(z)$, since the radius of convergence is the distance from the centre to the nearest singularity of the represented function, and raising to an integer power does not introduce singularities - it can, however, remove singularities.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it now. So we can say that if $R$ is the radius of convergence and if $\limsup_{z→z1}|P(z)|>0$ for any $|z1|=R$, then $P(z)^n$ has same radius of convergence as $P(z)$.

Comment: Right. Under those conditions, if $g(z) = P(z)^n$ had radius of convergence $> R$, then $\sqrt[n]{g(z)}$ would be holomorphic in a disk with radius $> R$.